# sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables

Tags: sudo

I have created few aliases, that I source to shell:

```
alias apti="apt-fast install -y"
alias aptr="apt-fast remove -y"
alias aptp="apt-fast purge -y"
alias apts="aptitude search"
alias aptu="sudo dpkg --configure -a; apti -f; apt-fast update; apt-fast upgrade -y; apt-fast full-upgrade -y; apt-fast autoremove -y"
```

and then added exceptions to /etc/sudoers:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

Cmnd_Alias APT=/usr/local/bin/apt
Cmnd_Alias DPKG=/usr/bin/dpkg
Cmnd_Alias APTGET=/usr/bin/apt-get
Cmnd_Alias APTITUDE=/usr/bin/aptitude
Cmnd_Alias APTFAST=/usr/sbin/apt-fast
Cmnd_Alias PM_SUSPEND=/usr/sbin/pm-suspend

myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: APT, DPKG, APTGET, APTITUDE, PM_SUSPEND, APTFAST
```

and it worked fine for years. But few weeks ago (linux mint update?) it started giving me error.

```
$ apti iridium-browser 
sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: DEBUG, LCK_FILE, DOWNLOADBEFORE, _APTMGR, APTCACHE, DLDIR, DLLIST, LISTDIR, _MAXNUM, _MAXCONPERSRV, _SPLITCON, _MINSPLITSZ, _PIECEALGO, aptfast_prefix, APT_FAST_TIMEOUT
```

In /etc/sudoers.d I have two files: README and mintupdate. I have not edited any of them. Only not commented lines are:

```
Cmnd_Alias UPDATE = /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/checkAPT.py

ALL ALL = NOPASSWD:UPDATE
```

As far as I can see, I am not setting any environment variables that are lissted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is apt-fast? https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast ?

Comment: Please post your whole sudo configuration (`/etc/sudoers` and files in `/etc/sudoers.d`. Also tell us how apt-fast calls sudo.

Comment: Will it work if you add this to `/etc/sudoers`: `Defaults env_keep="DEBUG"`

Comment: @derobert yes, apt-fast is multithreaded apt-get

Comment: @Gilles I have added full /etc/sudoers.d and non commented lines from all files in /etc/sudoers.d

Comment: @hschou I have added it. Same error.

Comment: If you're still having the problem, what is the result of `type sudo`? I imagine it will be something other than the standard `/usr/bin/sudo`, which means it's likely to be using a different configuration file somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error message when executing "sudo command" as a process in a lazarus program, but when I changed it to "/usr/bin/sudo command" it worked ok without the error, so it seems, in my case, that it is the missing path to 'sudo' that generates the error.

Comment: It sounds like you have two different versions of `sudo` on your system.